# Replace nth occurrence of a special character not working RegEx with Google Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to replace the nth occurrence of a character with the following function

It works for strings of letters but I want to replace the 2nd `[` in `[WORLD!] HELLO, [WORLD!]`

I am trying the pattern `/.\\[/` which works in RerEx tester but not in my function.  I get no error just no replacement

Thanks

```
function ReplaceNth_n() {

Logger.log(ReplaceNth("[WORLD!] HELLO, [WORLD!]", "/.\\[/", "M", 2))

}  

function ReplaceNth(strSearch,search_for, replace_with, Ocur) {
var nth = 0;
strSearch = strSearch.replace(new RegExp(search_for, 'g'), function (match, i, original) {
    nth++;
    return (nth === Ocur) ? replace_with : match;
});
return strSearch 
}
```

Comment: Instead of `new RegExp` and `"/.\\[/"` just use `/.\[/`. Not sure you want the dot in the pattern though.

Comment: If you are going to downvote my question then say what the problem is otherwise you just come off as a prima donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a regular expression with `RegExp`, you should not include the opening and closing `/` in the string, and I also don't understand why you added a `.` there.

- **Wrong**: `new RegExp("/test/");`
- **Correct**: `new RegExp("test");`

So the string passed as parameter for `search_for` should be `\\[`.

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you.  The `.` was there because I am very new to RegEx and was confused

Answer (score 1):

The *nth* occurrence.

```
^([^<char>]*(?:<char>[^<char>]*){<N-1>})<char>
```

Replace with `$1<repl_char>`

Where the regex string is constructed

```
regexStr = '^([^' + char + ']*(?:' + char + '[^' + char + ']*){' + (N-1) + '})' + char;
```

Where `char is to be found` and `N > 0`

Comment: @xyz - Wasn't that your question, the _Nth_ occurrence ?